# error on command npm start how to fix this

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

[Image of errors is attached please tell me how to fix this I am new to React and facing these issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uecZP.png)

Comment: We might be able to help you in a better way if you share the log file that npm generated. You can find it at the very end (screenshot). Would you mind changing the title too? This is something related to create-react-app, not only a generic "npm start" problem so it should be clear from the title. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run below commands

```
npm audit fix or npm audit
```

or

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```